# java checkstyle rule for non-static variable access to static variables

Tags: java, checkstyle, static-variables

Is there a Checkstyle rule available to restrict non-static access to static variables and methods?

This should raise a warning:

```
instance.staticField = value;
```

Eclipse has a setting for this, but I want to enforce it on the build.

Comment: Well, It Depends on your your build tool?

Comment: You mean you want to raise a compilation error when you use something like `instance.staticField = ...`?

Comment: yes, that is what I want to do

Answer (score 3):

I guess using `javac -Xlint:static -Werror toto.java` is what you're looking for.

From [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/javac.html) :

- `-Xlint:name` : Enable warning name. See the section [Warnings That Can Be Enabled or Disabled](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/javac.html#xlintwarnings) with -Xlint Option for a list of warnings you can enable with this option.
- `-Werror` : Terminate compilation if warnings occur.

I tried with this example :

```
public class StaticTest {
    public static String toto = "toto";

    public static void main(String s[]) {
        StaticTest st = new StaticTest();
        st.toto="dfd";
    }
}
```

and the output is:

> StaticTest.java:16: warning: [static] static variable should be qualified by type name,
>
> StaticTest, instead of by an expression
>
> ```
>    st.toto="dfd";
>
>      ^
> ```
>
> error: warnings found and -Werror specified
>   1 error
>   1 warning

Answer (score 1):

As it name indicates it, Checkstyle only check the form of your code. If you search bug patterns, you should take a look at Findbugs:

http://findbugs.sourceforge.net

Comment: I didn't see this in findbugs either unfortunately...I had checked there too.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Either [Firebug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FindBugs) or [PMD](http://pmd.sourceforge.net) for this purpose. Two major build tools `Maven` and `Ant` do have the command to do this for you.

Answer (score 1):

No, Checkstyle have limitation/scope for all checks - it examine structure of only one file, there is not ability to get structure of other class/file.